# Add an annotation to ggplot2 plot with a dynamic position / position relative to another element

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to add an annotation (a label) to a `ggplot2` plot (using `R`) with a position relative to another element, namely, above a bar in a bar chart.

I'm trying do this as part of a package, and (so) the following example is a bit contrived, but I hope it demonstrates the challenge.

Here is what I tried first, in which I position the label at the `y` variable value plus (so the label is above the bar) an additional 5% of the `y` variable's value.

```r
library(ggplot2)

d <- data.frame(x = c("var1", "var2"), y = c(.2, 4))

ggplot(d, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
    geom_col() +
    annotate("text", x = d$x, y = d$y + (.05 * d$y), label = "hi!")
```

[image]

Close, but not quite there. If I make this much larger than 5%, then the label on the bar for the larger `y` value becomes too far from the bar, whereas if I make this much smaller than 5%, then the label becomes too close to (and overlapping with) the bar.

I tried to take the square root of the `y` value:

```r
ggplot(d, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
    geom_col() +
    annotate("text", x = d$x, y = d$y + sqrt(.05 * d$y), label = "hi!")
```

[image]

This more or less works except in extreme cases for which this fails (the labels become very far or near the top of the bar) and so I am wondering whether there is a more general way to add a label (or another `ggplot2` annotation) relative to the position of another element in a more dynamic way.

Comment: How about `geom_text()` with a `vjust`? `ggplot(d, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_col() + geom_text(aes( label = "hi!"), vjust = -0.5)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using `vjust` with `geom_text()`:

```
ggplot(d, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_col() + geom_text(aes( label = "hi!"), vjust = -0.5)
```

Should work pretty well even in extreme cases:

```
d <- data.frame(x = c("var1", "var2"), y = c(.2, 100))
```

[image]